# Avoiding apply when indexing matrix by combinations of rows

Tags: r, optimization, combinations, apply

I have two inputs in the following formats:

```
domains = list(
    O60925 = "PF01920",
    P01130 = c("PF07645", "PF00057", "PF00058"),
    Q14764 = c("PF11978", "PF01505"),
    Q9BX68 = "PF01230",
    P46777 = "PF14204")

interactions = structure(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(8L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("PF01920", 
"PF07645", "PF00057", "PF00058", "PF11978", "PF01505", "PF01230", 
"PF14204"), c("PF01920", "PF07645", "PF00057", "PF00058", "PF11978", 
"PF01505", "PF01230", "PF14204")))

        PF01920 PF07645 PF00057 PF00058 PF11978 PF01505 PF01230 PF14204
PF01920       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       0
PF07645       0       1       0       1       0       0       0       0
PF00057       0       0       1       1       0       0       0       0
PF00058       0       1       1       1       0       0       0       0
PF11978       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0
PF01505       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0
PF01230       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       0
PF14204       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

I would like to calculate the following output, where the integer in each cell represents the total sum of all cells in the `interactions` matrix for each pair of names in the `domains` list.

```
       O60925 P01130 Q14764 Q9BX68 P46777
O60925      1      0      0      1      0
P01130      0      7      0      0      0
Q14764      0      0      2      0      0
Q9BX68      1      0      0      1      0
P46777      0      0      0      0      0
```

The context is that I have a list of proteins (the names of the `domains` list) and their Pfam domains (the entries in the `domains` list), and a matrix of known Pfam domain-Pfam domain interactions (the `interactions` matrix). I would like to sum the total number of known domain-domain interactions for each protein pair.

In reality the `domains` list and `interactions` matrix are both much larger than these, so I would like to identify a fast method of generating this results matrix. However, the only solution I have been able to come up with so far is an `apply` loop:

```
proteins = names(domains)
result = matrix(0, nrow = length(proteins), ncol = length(proteins),
dimnames = list(proteins, proteins))
combinations = tidyr::crossing(proteins, proteins)
n_interactions = apply(combinations, 1, function(row) {
  domains1 = domains[[row[1]]]
  domains2 = domains[[row[2]]]
  sum(interactions[as.matrix(crossing(domains1, domains2))])
})
result[as.matrix(combinations)] = n_interactions
```

I am sure there must be a faster way to do this, but how?

Comment: your expected output doesn't really match the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your matrices are sorted like the example, you can be clever with some matrix algebra:

```
columnBuilder <- function(m,l,n){
  rep.int(c(0,1,0),
          c(l,n,m-n-l))
}


matrixBuilder <- function(domainList){
  groupSizes <- sapply(domains,length)
  leadingZeros <- cumsum(c(0,groupSizes))
  m <- sum(groupSizes)

  sapply(seq_along(groupSizes),
         function(i){
           columnBuilder(m,leadingZeros[[i]],groupSizes[[i]])
         })
}

magicFunction <- function(interactionsM, domainL){
  magicMatrix <- matrixBuilder(domainL)

  output <- t(magicMatrix) %*% interactionsM %*% magicMatrix
  colnames(output) <- rownames(output) <- names(domainL)
  output

}

magicFunction(interactions, domains)

           O60925 P01130 Q14764 Q9BX68 P46777
O60925      1      0      0      1      0
P01130      0      7      0      0      0
Q14764      0      0      2      0      0
Q9BX68      1      0      0      1      0
P46777      0      0      0      0      0
```

The cool thing about this is 
1. you should always be able to sort your matrix to use this method 
2. this shouldn't be memory intensive 
3. you can modify this to build only a single column of the `magicMatrix`, multiply like in the larger case and you'll end up with just a single column from the final output. You don't have to run the whole algorithm to get at the columns you want to see! And as for bencmarks:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  OP = {
    proteins = names(domains)
    result = matrix(0, nrow = length(proteins), ncol = length(proteins),
                    dimnames = list(proteins, proteins))
    combinations = tidyr::crossing(proteins, proteins)
    n_interactions = apply(combinations, 1, function(row) {
      domains1 = domains[[row[1]]]
      domains2 = domains[[row[2]]]
      sum(interactions[as.matrix(tidyr::crossing(domains1, domains2))])
    })
    result[as.matrix(combinations)] = n_interactions
  },
  privefl = {
    n <- length(domains)
    res <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n)
    res[] <- purrr::pmap_dbl(expand.grid(domains, domains),
                             function(Var1,Var2){sum(interactions[Var1, Var2])}) 
    colnames(res) <- rownames(res) <- names(domains)
  },
  matrixAlgebra = {
    magicFunction(interactions, domains)
  },


  times = 10
)



Unit: microseconds
          expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq        max neval
            OP 18996.486 20218.043 33483.5307 21058.912 22152.479 143394.733    10
       privefl   406.579   424.811   467.1096   448.513   475.861    642.503    10
 matrixAlgebra    72.200    95.902   123.1771   111.946   137.471    261.085    10
```

Comment: I think this is a very convenient approach. It can, also, be simplified only as `domains.tab = table(rev(stack(domains)))[names(domains), colnames(interactions)]; tcrossprod(tcrossprod(domains.tab, interactions), domains.tab)`

Comment: That is cool. Thank you for adding. It's slower than using matrices directly but I wanted to get a `table` version when I set out and couldn't work it out. Now you've shown me how.

Comment: Another way to work with matrices as "raw" as possible would be through matrix indexing (though I'd guess `table`'s overhead won't be as apparent in a bigger dataset), i.e. build "magicMatrix" with something like `rnm = names(domains); cnm = colnames(interactions); domains.tab = array(0L, c(length(rnm), length(cnm)), list(rnm, cnm)); domains.tab[cbind(rep(rnm, lengths(domains)), unlist(domains, , FALSE))] = 1L`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
n <- length(domains)
res <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n)
res[] <- purrr::pmap_dbl(expand.grid(domains, domains), 
                         ~ sum(interactions[.x, .y])) 
colnames(res) <- rownames(res) <- names(domains)
```

In fact, this is not much different from what you did.

---

Benchmark:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  OP = {
    proteins = names(domains)
    result = matrix(0, nrow = length(proteins), ncol = length(proteins),
                    dimnames = list(proteins, proteins))
    combinations = tidyr::crossing(proteins, proteins)
    n_interactions = apply(combinations, 1, function(row) {
      domains1 = domains[[row[1]]]
      domains2 = domains[[row[2]]]
      sum(interactions[as.matrix(crossing(domains1, domains2))])
    })
    result[as.matrix(combinations)] = n_interactions
  },
  privefl = {
    n <- length(domains)
    res <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n)
    res[] <- purrr::pmap_dbl(expand.grid(domains, domains), 
                             ~ sum(interactions[.x, .y])) 
    colnames(res) <- rownames(res) <- names(domains)
  },
  times = 10
)
```

---

Result:

```
Unit: microseconds
    expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
      OP 208685.225 209913.891 231506.172 210817.264 213071.475 416724.50    10
 privefl    262.885    281.426   1580.779    306.092    396.975  12842.56    10
```